# Open messenger with product info

Tags: next.js, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have searched for this feature, but I'm not sure if it is possible and maybe someone has done this before. I would like to integrate chat messenger (facebook) with my website,  and I would like to have a buy button on my products, and when someone clicks it, it would open the messenger popup with the info about the product clicked already filled in, so I can just follow up personally with extra questions (quantity, address,prices, etc)

Is it possible?

The website is being built with nextjs by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can not popup the chat extension provided by Facebook automatically the way you are wanting. But, what you can do to achieve your goal is to use Chatbot and referral codes. You can identify which product page the user have come from by checking the referral code. And your chatbot can then provide response of that product as per referral code.

Reference: [Messenger m.me Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links/)